# Can't create Amazon Web Services (AWS) credentials object

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to get started developing against the local Dynamo DB service.  The first step is simply creating a client:

```
var storedAWSCreds = new StoredProfileAWSCredentials();
```

This throws an exception:

> App.config does not contain credentials information. Either add the
>   AWSAccessKey and AWSSecretKey or AWSProfileName

My app.config has the needed properties:

```
<add key="AWSProfileName" value="justin"/>
<add key="AWSProfilesLocation" value="C:\code\dynamodb\credentials"/>
```

The credentials profile file:

```
justin
aws_access_key_id = REMOVED-FOR-POST
aws_secret_access_key = REMOVED-FOR-POST
```

At this point I thought I would try one of the other overloaded methods and explicitly tell the constructor what the parameters should be:

```
var storedAWSCreds = new StoredProfileAWSCredentials("justin", @"C:\code\dynamodb\credentials");
```

Again, the same exception.

Okay, the exception says I can provide the credentials directly in my config so I tried that:

```
<add key="AWSAccessKey" value="REMOVED-FOR-POST"/>
<add key="AWSSecretKey" value="REMOVED-FOR-POST"/>
```

Again, the same exception.

How can I get the `StoredProfileAWSCredentials` object created?  I'm clearly missing something obvious or their exception messages are incorrect.

I will point out, I can create a `BasicAWSCredentials` object by specifying the access key and secret key in the constructor:

```
var basicAWSCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials("REMOVED-FOR-POST", "REMOVED-FOR-POST");
```

But, at some point I would prefer to not have it hard-coded in my application.

Comment: Simple question: is your app.config being copied correctly to the executing directory?

Comment: @SvenGrosen - Yep, I'm running the application directly from Visual Studio as I'm trying to develop against a local DynamoDB instance.

Comment: The following might be helpful: According to https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=567665 - "This exception message is a bit misleading, but it generally means that the SDK has tried to lookup the profile you specified and was unable to find it"

Answer (score 5):

Your config section

```xml
<add key="AWSProfilesLocation" value="C:\code\dynamodb\credentials" />
```

should be

```xml
<add key="AWSProfilesLocation" value="C:\code\dynamodb\credentials\filename.json" />
```

for it to work. In other words specify the file name in the Profile location.

If you using newer SDK then using the following would work as well:

```xml
<configSections>
   <section name="aws" type="Amazon.AWSSection, AWSSDK" />
</configSections>
<aws profileName="YourProfileName" profilesLocation="C:\aws\credentials\aws-credentialfile.json" region="xx-xxxx-x" />
```

Nachi

Answer (score 1):

The profile name needs to be in square brackets, like so

```
[justin]
aws_access_key_id = REMOVED-FOR-POST
aws_secret_access_key = REMOVED-FOR-POST
```